# Excel VBA getting and using Name of Table

Tags: excel, vba

I got stuck at a problem with Excel VBA.

I am supposed to do the kinda easy task of copy/paste a variable range of cells from "sheet2" into the same range in "sheet1".

500 Rows like in my code is far too much, but I tried it this way, to "catch" the variable aspect.

**The tricky part is, that the range in "sheet1" is a table(which gets created from TFS).**

```
Sub CopyP()


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:F500").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:F500").Value

SheetObject.ListObjects (ListObjectName)
Range("NAME OF TABLE[Iteration Path]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The [Iteration Path] is a column name of my table, i want to check in this column/with this parameter, if the "row" is empty.

I know the code is far from being good or clean but the table is giving me a hard time copying.

With this code I got another problem: the table gets created from TFS, no problem to copy into that, BUT the name of the table is variable(seems like TFS creates the name), so unless I put the name manually in the code, the "program" cant execute, because of missing range.

Didn't find a way to get a return of the table name somehow.

But I think I am just following the wrong path overall, maybe someone can be bring me on the right track.

My other Idea is to Iterate through the Rows in Sheet 2 to fetch just as much data is needed and then copy them with an iteration into the table. But i guess I would be the same problem with the table-name there.

Every information I find using google , talks about tables where the user can "name" the table. In my case I cant, so I have to work with the name TFS uses for my table.

Comment: Posting from phone so please ignore typos. If there is only one table then you can get the name by looping though listobject object. I don't have access to excel right now else I would have given you an example

Comment: Sadly i really need an example to understand it. It would be awesome if you could give me one in the next few days! Edit: Yes there is only one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comments below your question, I just typed this in notepad. Please amend it to suit your need.

This will give you the names of all tables in the activesheet. If there are multiple tables then you will get multiple names. (UNTESTED AS POSTING FROM PHONE)

```
Sub sample()
    Dim objLB As ListObject, TableName As String

    For Each objLB In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        TableName = objLB.Name
        Exit For
    Next

    Range(TableName & "[Iteration Path]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: ok this works so far, thanks for that ! But i do have a last question to it. While debugging i can see the value stored in objLB , but if I try to use objLB in :                                                                             Range("NAME OF TABLE[Iteration Path]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete           i still get a range error. Or did i use the variable wrong?

Comment: So what else do you now?

Comment: Basicly i just want to use the name of the table to delete every empty row in it. Thats what:     Range("NAME OF TABLE[Iteration Path]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete , does.

Comment: Sadly no. I still get a Run-timer error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed

Comment: Ok i will look at this later tonight when I have access to Excel. Can you upload a sample file in wikisend.com and share a link here. You can put fictitious data if the data is sensitive. Also leave your code as it is in that file.

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/914120/exceltotfs.xlsm ........  i did a little mistake with the new table. the column ID has to be in column A not B. Guess it doesnt matter for the problem, but just saying

Comment: I will have a look at the code when i get back but I hope you are using `objLB` in the code correctly? For example `Range(objLB.Name & "[Iteration Path]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Yeah i do. Tryed both: Range(objLB.Name .... ) and Range(objLB...) just to get sure i didnt miss something.

Comment: I just made few changes to the above post. Please test it